# jQuery Console Error: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script smooth scrolls my #anchor links and creates the appropriate offset due to a fixed header that varies in height.

After a few hours of troubleshooting/researching this, I cannot figure out why 'top' is undefined. **Everything works as expected**, but this error always occurs when I click the nav (a.anchorlink) from **another page**. Just before the page loads, this error pops up in the console. When the page then loads, this error is gone.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var $root = $('html, body');

    function getFixedOffset($) {
        if($(window).scrollTop() === 0) {
            return 100;
        }
        else {
            return 55;
        }
    }

    $('a.anchorlink').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        var targetID = href.substr(href.indexOf("#") + 1);

        if (targetID.length) {
            var lengthID = $("#" + targetID).offset().top;

            $root.animate({
                scrollTop: lengthID - getFixedOffset($)
            }, 850, function() {
                window.location.hash = lengthID;
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li"><a href="/about#mission" class="anchorlink">Sub-link 1</a></li>
  <li"><a href="/about#history" class="anchorlink">Sub-link 2</a></li>
</ul>
<!-- All other pages don't have hashes and will spit the error before load -->
```

As you can see, I've ensured targetID exists (is not zero) in order to request the top property. Are there additional steps I can take or would you need more information about the page that is spitting the error?

Comment: can you share relevant markup?

Comment: @gurvinder372 like HTML? Please be specific and I'll get it to you.

Comment: Yes, please share the relevant HTML to this problem\

Comment: The error means that the `offset` returned from `$("#" + targetID).offset()` is undefined, which in turn means the `targetID` element isn't present in the DOM.

Comment: Given your updated HTML I can see it's because the `#mission` and `#history` elements do not exist.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I've added the sub-menu with my anchors/hashes I click on from any other page. If I am located in /about* it just smooth scrolls to it without error. However, when I click from any other page, I get the error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, that is interesting. Could you provide more detail so I can get this issue resolved?

Comment: That's about all the detail I can provide given the code you've shown. The problem is simply that those elements are not in the DOM when you try and select them.

Comment: What would the solution be in that case? If I can provide more information that would be beneficial, let me know.

Comment: I suggest to you do the next because of probably you element target doesn't exists:  `if (targetID.length && $("#" + targetID).length > 0) {...`

Comment: @ChristopherDíaz!!! THAT WAS IT!!! Thank you! Please make an answer so I can select your solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to you do the next because of probably you element target doesn't exists:

```
if (targetID.length && $("#" + targetID).length > 0) {...
```

You only was verifying the href's content but not if the element in DOM exists. So, with this double check, you ensure to try to do something with an non existent element.